# Slick Show One in the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi Everyone I am trying to show one by one product in the center. I have this slide to show products in cards so I need to show in the center which I stay in a moment. I am using slick javascript-lib. So I dont have that property to do that. Please I Would like to something help to reach this. Thanks to everyone for any help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css" />
     <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <style type="text/css">
         html,
         body {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }

         * {
             box-sizing: border-box;
         }

         .slider {
             width: 80%;
             margin: 100px auto;
         }

         .slick-slide {
             margin: 0px 20px;
         }

         .slick-slide img {
             width: 80%;
             height: 50%;
             padding: 20px;
         }

         .slick-prev:before,
         .slick-next:before {
             color: black;
         }

         .slick-slide {
             transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
             opacity: .2;
         }

         .slick-active {
             opacity: .5;
         }

         .slick-current {
             opacity: 1;
         }

         .card {
             width: 350px;
         }
     </style> </head>

 <body>
     <main>
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                 <section class="regular slider">

                     <div class="card">
                         <img class="card-img"
                             src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/vans.png"
                             alt="Vans">
                         <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-end">
                             <a href="#" class="card-link text-danger like">
                                 <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
                             </a>
                         </div>
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title">Vans Sk8-Hi MTE Shoes</h5>
                             <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Style: VA33TXRJ5</h6>
                             <p class="card-text">
                                 The Vans All-Weather MTE Collection features footwear and apparel designed to withstand
                                 the elements whilst still looking cool. </p>

                             <div class="buy d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                 <div class="price text-success">
                                     <h5 class="mt-4">$125</h5>
                                 </div>
                                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mt-3"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to
                                     Cart</a>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top"
                             src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bootstrapbaymisc/blog/24_days_bootstrap/vans.png"
                             alt="Card image cap">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                             <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                                 of the card's content.</p>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>


                     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                             <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                                 of the card's content.</p>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                             <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                                 of the card's content.</p>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                         <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                         <div class="card-body">
                             <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                             <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk
                                 of the card's content.</p>
                             <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </section>
             </div>
         </div>
     </main>


     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popper.min.js" ></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mdb.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

     <script>
         $(document).on('ready', function () {
             $(".regular").slick({               
                 centerPadding: '60px',
                 dots: false,
                 infinite: true,
                 speed: 300,
                 slidesToShow: 4,
                 slidesToScroll: 1,
                 variableWidth: true,
                 responsive: [
                     {
                         breakpoint: 1024,
                         settings: {
                             slidesToShow: 3,
                             slidesToScroll: 3,
                            infinite: true,
                             dots: true
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         breakpoint: 600,
                         settings: {
                             slidesToShow: 2,
                             slidesToScroll: 2
                         }
                     },
                     {
                         breakpoint: 480,
                         settings: {
                             slidesToShow: 1,
                             slidesToScroll: 1
                         }
                     }
                     // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
                     // settings: "unslick"
                     // instead of a settings object
                 ]
             });



         });
     </script> </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: How many slides you want to see per view? only 1 big or some small and the center bigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very own [demos page of the slick plugin](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#demos) has exactly what you want, and a number of variations on the concept, with the code snippets to achieve it. More than that, if I understood you right, what you want is the default behavior. Did you copy your snippet from somewhere? I might be wrong, but in your configuration object you just need to remove the `slidesToShow` property, or set it to one, or if you want to show more than one slide, but just center the current one, you can set `centerMode: true`.